# What's a word for someone who takes advantage of an unfortunate situation as an opportunity for self-improvement?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, compliment

In a good way, so no negative connotations. The best way to explain it is using the saying: "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade". This person would make "lemonade" when life throws "lemons" at them. It's a good thing. Is there a word that specifically describes this?

Not optimistic.

I wanted to add that I've actually thought about this for days. The closest word I found was "can-do", meaning "confident and resourceful in the face of challenges". However, it's too informal for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Someone who is effective in a difficult situation is *resourceful*.

Someone who perseveres is *steadfast* or a *stoic* (or *stoical*).

Comment: This is kind of a stupid question, but would it seem like I'm saying the person is using their unfortunate situation as a 'resource' for self-improvement? Because that just seems a bit weird.

Comment: The word *resourceful* doesn't refer to use of resources. One meaning of *resource* is that it is an action that you can take in an emergency. It is something to which you *resort*.

Comment: @Blue, the implication is more often that they are using their own innate resources.

Answer (score 1):

"Opportunist" fits the definition.

Comment: Doesn't it have a negative connotation?

Comment: It has the connotation of doing something "with no regard for principles or consequences." That's pretty negative.

Comment: Not necessarily negative, but having no care for whether or not the outcome is good or bad for anyone else. So negative or positive. I still don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I was aware that opportunist can be used negatively but surprised that the definition at dictionary.com included the sacrifice of ethical principles. However it also gave a definition from the World English Dictionary: "a person who adapts his actions, responses, etc, to take advantage of opportunities, circumstances, etc" which is exactly how I meant it.

Answer (score 0):

equanimous.
unflappable.
stalwart.
unflenching.
bursting.
budding
blooming
growing
tackling
owning
bringing
pushing
ploughing through

Comment: I notice that all your examples mention 'business'. Though the OP didn't ask for anything related to business, was there something in the question that made you feel that 'business' is necessary?

Comment: Thank you for voicing my thoughts. (And in case it isn't clear to anyone else, this has nothing to do with business.)

Comment: I was assuming self improvement as a business man.  But I guess its true you don't have to be a businessman to self-improve.

Comment: Not just to self-improve, but to achieve self-improvement _by taking advantage of unfortunate circumstances_

Comment: owning is a good one b/c you own to self improve and you have to own something in order to take advantage of it even if its an unfortunate circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

*Positive*.

["tending towards progress or improvement; moving in a beneficial direction"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/positive)

A positive person makes the best of a bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

bold

[bohld]

adjective, bolder, boldest.

1. not hesitating or fearful in the face of actual or possible danger or rebuff; courageous and daring:
   a bold hero.
2. not hesitating to break the rules of propriety; forward; impudent:
   He apologized for being so bold as to speak to the emperor.
3. necessitating courage and daring; challenging:
   a bold adventure.
4. beyond the usual limits of conventional thought or action; imaginative:
   Einstein was a bold mathematician. a difficult problem needing a bold answer.
5. striking or conspicuous to the eye; flashy; showy:
   a bold pattern.
6. steep; abrupt:
   a bold promontory.
7. Nautical. deep enough to be navigable close to the shore:
   bold waters.

Idioms:

1. be /make (so) bold, to presume or venture; dare:
   I made bold to offer my suggestion.

-http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bold

Comment: What is your source for this?