# A positive word for 'opportunist'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, connotation, compliment

The word *opportunist* seems to be used negatively for a person.

Is there a word with the same but positive meaning?

Comment: In other words, one who never lets an opportunity pass him by. However, I'm not sure if a single word exists to describe such a person. Maybe there is.

Comment: There's certainly a single word available to describe such a person, but it's not a noun: **resourceful**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a word for someone who takes advantage of an unfortunate situation as an opportunity for self-improvement?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97454/whats-a-word-for-someone-who-takes-advantage-of-an-unfortunate-situation-as-an)

Comment: If the opportunist has political or economic power over you, you could try "beloved leader."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in the US we would say, "He is a **go-getter**."  The word **ambitious** and **proactive** both are very positive and may fit your context too.

Comment: I think I have got many near words. But proactive is suiting my need for now. So, I am marking it as right answer for me.

Answer (score 3):

In the economic sphere, we have *entrepreneur*. More generally, we have *initiative-taker, visionary, instigator, revolutionary, far-sighted person, strategist, tactician...*

Comment: '... we have entrepreneur.' Unlike, apparently, the French.

Comment: Not even we have 'day-seizer'. Though 'King for a Day' is well known. Staying in the Latin quarter: I can't noun 'carpe diem' nicely. It's tempting to anagramise it.

Comment: Perhaps "I, decamper" for your French friend? (Ed, I carp 'em!)

Answer (score 2):

For a everyday usage I think that **artful** may describe a person who is attentive to  his own personal  advantage without having necessarily negative implications.

*Artful*

- skillful or clever in adapting means to ends; ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

In the literary sphere, we have the [Randian hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randian_hero#Characteristics)--an ideal person "who perseveres to achieve his values, even when his ability and independence leads to conflict with others."

And also the [antihero](http://english.learnhub.com/lesson/7614-anti-heroes-in-literature), who "doesn't always think about what the right, moral thing to do - he often thinks about what's right for him."

Answer (score 0):

As an opportunist takes advantage of situations for a short term or selfish gain, I don't see how another word can be positive and still mean the same thing.  A similar term such as *investor* could be considered more positive in most cases, as it implies a longer and (possibly) beneficial outlook.

Comment: I don't see why there couldn't be a term for someone who takes advantage of an opportunity to benefit their community (or indeed society as a whole).

Comment: @ErikKowal Agreed. Even it is not for the community or someone else, a person can still be insightful and active for his own benefit but avoid taking selfish means, right?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it occurs to me that _social entrepreneur_ is a relatively recent coinage for just such a type of person.

Comment: Yes, thats a good point, which reminds me of philanthropist too.

Answer (score -1):

Another single word thats negative i would say thief. Its amazing how we use the same word , but we have different feelings.

Comment: The OP asked for a word with a *positive connotation*. I don't think "thief" meets that criteria.

Comment: @Chenmunka Why do you say that? It may be a wrong answer, but it's still an answer.